# Is there any way to insert javacode in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Is there any way to put my java code in firebase(realtimedatabase) and then retrieve it and also call it
for example if i have a button and in the button i have toast funktion like                `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`for example

can i put this code in my firebase and then retrieve it when i press the button ?

Comment: Yes. It would be stored as a string. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I can do that as a string but i mean the java code not the string

Comment: The Java code *is a string*. It would not compile or run in Firebase but you can certainly store the string in Firebase, read it in, copy to the clipboard and paste it into a javascript engine to run the string as code.

Comment: Any docu about it?

Comment: Documentation about how to store strings in Firebase? Yes - there are a ton of examples here on SO and the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) is a great place to start. You could store the sting in either the Firebase Real Time Database or [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) - just depends on your use case.